# How does "И, может быть, это и проблема" translate?

Tags: грамматика, выражения

I am trying to read some basic Russian texts to strengthen my vocabulary and I came across the following sentence in one of them:

> И, может быть, это и проблема...

I am yet to fully comprehend the intricacies of the Russian language, but I did struggle to translate this one properly. Apparently, the correct translation is:

> And maybe this is the problem...

How does one get to this end result? I know I need to try and stop reading a sentence word by word in the hope it will make sense immediately, but there are a few things I do not understand regarding the aforementioned phrase:

1. As far as I am aware *может* can mean *May, or Can (as in "Can I", "May I")* so where does this come in with *может быть*, and how does that end up meaning *Maybe*?
2. In the phrase *это и проблема... (this is the problem)* why is *и* present? I thought that meant *and*?

Comment: "Может" — "may", "быть" — "be", "может быть" — "maybe". The "и" here is an emphatic particle, with no actual meaning, you can translate it by boldening "is": "this **is** a problem".

Comment: Is it a whole phrase?

Comment: **And possibly, precisely this is the problem**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> И, может быть, это и проблема...

The original sentence  *doesn't* sound perfect Russian to me: it's even unclear, which of the two senses it was supposed to express:

1) **And that might also be a problem**,

2) **And maybe the problem** [we are trying to locate] **is just in that**.

That is because the *second* "**и**"  can function (1) like **ещё и** (*also, as well*) or (2) simply *emphasize* the following word.
Also, the first comma looks redundant: in case it was used in pair with the second one, to isolate the insert **может быть**, that does not work well because extracting the insert (a typical punctuation test) brings us to an internally strange sentence "**И это и проблема**". So the first "**И**" is rather a part of "**И может быть**".

Comment: The first variant is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on a context, but here it reflects the 'probability'.
'А, может быть, это и проблема." - 'something is probably a problem' - "что-то, вероятно, является проблемой [для кого-либо]".